# Good Book on survival analysis

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a comprehensive textbook on survival analysis, either in German or English, from the basics to modern methods including competing risks. It should be easier to understand than the Kalbfleisch & Prentice book "The Statistical Analysis of Failure Time Data", which has some terrible notations, e.g. in the unification of discrete, continuous and mixed distributions, many references to derivations later in the book, and inconsistent terms - for example, lambda stands for both the hazard function and the parameter of the exponential distribution, and in places where both are discussed, it is not always clear what is meant.